# TestNG is not failing the Test case even when Assertion is failing

Tags: java, rest, testng, rest-assured, assertion

```
@Test
public void getProfile() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = URL.baseURL;
    Response res = given().header(URL.contentType, 
               URL.cookieType).when().get(URL.getURL).then().assertThat().
               statusCode(200).and().extract().response();
    String data = res.asString();
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Following is the output of the test run:

```
{"status_code":401,"message":"Authentication failed."}
```

TestNG now marks this case as PASS even though the response is not as expected. How can i make this to work? I want to go through with assertThat statement only.

Comment: This is insufficient information, we cannot see what actually happened and have no way to tell where the problem is.  Can you add a capture of the HTTP traffic?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger? Try splitting up the long set of chained method calls into individual lines and either step through or print debug output at each step to determine what is actually occurring.

Comment: Your output shows response body, not status code. It can return 200 OK and any reponse body. Check res.statusCode(). RestAssured throws an exception when some expectation failed and with exception thrown TestNG fails the test

Answer (score 1):

You must save the test result into a boolean or numeric value.

Later you must compare the expected test result with the actual test result using Assert:

```
Boolean testPassed = isTestPassed();
Assert.assertTrue("The test result is: "+testPassed,testPassed);
```

Numeric comparison:

```
long testValue = getTestResponseCode();
Assert.assertEquals("Actual test respoonse code is: "+testValue,testValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of below .

```
given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).queryParam("text","lands").when().get("http://services.groupkt.com/country/search").then().assertThat().statusCode(200).log().all();

            int actualStatusCode=given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).queryParam("page","2").when().get("https://reqres.in/api/users").statusCode();
            Assert.assertEquals(200, actualStatusCode,"The status code mistatches");
```